# Does every .h file have a corresponding object file?

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, object-files

I'm trying to write a makefile, but I don't really understand how object files work. There are no `.o` files in my folder, so how can I be compiling them? Does every `.h` file have a corresponding `.o`? If not, then how do we know if we have to compile an object file or not? Sorry if these are stupid questions, I'm new to programming.

Thank you.

Comment: You don't need an `.o` file if you're just declaring structures, not functions.

Comment: Every .c file is compiled into a .o by the compiler. Whether or not .h files exist and what they do is up to the programmer. They are only dependencies, they do not create object files of their own.

Comment: You can put the functions in the same `.c` file as the caller, while still having a separate `.h` file for the declarations, but that would be a perverse thing to do.

Comment: I see. Let's say I'm trying to compile a program through a makefile, and that program depends on 2 .c files, both of which have no .h files that they depend on. When I compile the .o files, I'll only have to write down the corresponding .c files as the files that they depend on, right?

Comment: @user494405 Yes. And you might need to link the two `.o` files later.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry but, I don't understand what you mean by "link the two .o files". What does that mean?

Comment: Looks like you need to step back where the executable build process is explained. Without it you can't do anything meaningful with makefiles.

Comment: @user494405: If you are just starting, I suggest you ignore Makefiles altogether *for the moment* until you understand the language better. Compile your code passing all the source files (i.e. `.c`) to the compiler at once, so that the compiler performs both the compiling and the linking for you in one single step. This will also avoid having to deal with intermediate object files (i.e. `.o`).

Comment: If your program has two .c files, then at least one of them must have a corresponding .h file. For example, if file a.c contains a call to a function in b.c, then a,c must include a b.h file that specifies the prototypes of the functions in b.c

Comment: Ohhh, of course, that makes sense, thank you. To the rest of you, I do agree that I need to get more comfortable before learning any more on makefiles. I just wanted to learn the very basic basics. Thank you!

Comment: Another thing that might be helpful to you in the future - when replying to comments made by anyone than the poster of the respective question/answer, using @<username> sends the user a notification. Else, they may not even know you responded.

Comment: @GoodDeeds Ah, that would explain why sometimes the person wouldn't reply. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

Basically the header (.h) files tell the compiler that things exist when it's generating the object (.o) files. The compiler generates object files from source (.c/.cpp/etc.) files. If the compiler doesn't know specifically about something, it assumes the header was right and leaves a "name" behind for the linker.

The linker will take the object files and generate an executable by replacing "names" in the object code with code from other object files.

This is a **very** high level overview of what happens. There are many many pages on the specifics.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer to illustrate the overall concept:

Every .c file contains program code which is translated by the compiler into an .o file containing the machine code.

Usually different .c files are combined to one software. But then they must 
somehow be connected. Hence their .o files must be connected to an
executable. This is what the linker does.

The .h files describe connection points of .c files.

The linker uses  the .c file connections to produce the software.

This is a simplification, however:

For example, the .h files are *not* consulted by the linker. They merely serve 
the compiler to tell him that a certain symbol is a connection point the linker must resolve.

The .h files are for conveniance of the software developper. When a .c file has "connection points" for the linker its peer .h file may list them all. 
If another .c file wants to use them it may just include the corresponding .h file. But this is just a convention. Theoretically, only the .c files are essential. In theory every software project could be written with .c files only (however, mostly not in due time).